# Generating IL for double arrays

Tags: c#, il

I’m writing some IL institutions for creating `int` and `double` arrays using System.Reflection.Emit name space.

For creating `int` array I’m using following code.

```
LocalBuilder arr = gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(int));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, arr);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arr);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 500);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arr);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_I4);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call,typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",new Type[]{typeof(int)}));
```

It’s working as expected and prints 500 on the Console.

Same way I tried to create `double` array as shown below.

```
LocalBuilder arr = gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(double));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(double));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, arr);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arr);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8, 500D);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_R8);

gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arr);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_I8);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call,typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",new Type[]{typeof(double)}));
```

Unfortunately this doesn’t work and when I inspect generated assembly using `pereview` it gave me following error.

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[IL]: Error: [C:\temp\Research\Research\bin\Debug\MyMod.exe : Foo::Main][offset 0x00000006][found ref array md
array 'System.Double[]'][expected Double] Unexpected type on the stack.
[IL]: Error: [C:\temp\Research\Research\bin\Debug\MyMod.exe : Foo::Main][offset 0x00000012] Expected single di
mension array.
2 Error(s) Verifying MyMod.exe
```

Furthermore, I inspected generated assembly using `ildasm`

```
.method privatescope static void  Main$PST06000001() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       28 (0x1c)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init (float64 V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0001:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Double
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0009:  ldc.r8     500.
  IL_0012:  stelem.r8
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0015:  ldelem.i8
  IL_0016:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
  IL_001b:  ret
} // end of method Foo::Main
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does a C# generated il snippet look like?

Comment: I admit I'm pretty shoddy at IL, but aren't you storing an array reference into a local variable of declared type (int/double)? Shouldn't that local be a reference of some sort?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Yes I have done a mistake and have incorrectly assigned array reference into a integer variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LocalBuilder arr = gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(int));
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, arr);
```

Why is the `arr` not of type `int[]`?

I am certain peverify would complain for both versions.

The fact that it runs for the first version is simply 'luck'*.

`*` The reason is much more complex.

Comment: Thanks I have done a BIG mistake, variable type should be double [] After than change my code works
 LocalBuilder arr = gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(double[]));   Unfortunately for int[] array example works with 

LocalBuilder arr = gen.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

Comment: @Upul: The reason is complex why it works. The system sees the `int` as compatible with a pointer type. Similar to what C allows you to do.

Comment: I'm on x86 here - I assume it would fall over on x64? (Also, isn't it technically a reference rather than a pointer)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Not sure  :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, x64 has 8-byte pointers, x86 4-byte * (again, more complex :-) and both have 4-byte int's, so implicitly 'casting' it to an array of int's will probably not get an 'out-of-bounds'. That said, the JIT'ter for x64 and x86 are quite different and there's no telling what the optimizer / debug mode does with it, so eventually it all boils down to "luck". Either case, I believe the 'lesson learned' here should be: always use PEVerify when you are building IL code.